# Current from thermocouple (T/C)

Tags: temperature, multimeter, thermocouple

Studying thermocouples (T/C), I have a question regarding the output.
Generally speaking, in the case of T/C, we measure the thermoelectric voltage in millivolts.

Why do we calculate not current, but voltage?
I think T/C has current output too.

When I measure current via multimeter, I have seen the current is changed.

My guess is...Current is generated, but not proportional to temperature.
Current does not have linearity.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful here, you might be the victim of a classic illusion of electrical engineering! Thermocouples do not "produce" or "generate" a voltage, as many books, on-line tutorials, magazine article, and well-meaning EE savants will consistently suggest.

The temperature-dependent voltage you measure as the "output" of the thermocouple  is actually the difference of voltages produced by the two individual wires that  make up the thermocouple. Each wire produces a voltage (potential difference) from one of its ends to the other end, which is temperature dependent. This voltage is called the "Seebeck voltage". You don't need two wires to produce it just one!

The Seebeck voltage is very tricky to measure because you have  to connect the  voltage  measuring device between the two ends of the wire producing/exhibiting the temperature dependent voltage. There are two problems: A) the measuring device changes the temperature of the end of the wire  to which it is connected, & B) the wires of the measuring device also are subject to Seebeck  voltage effects. (Yes, copper wires produce a Seebeck Voltage, if the ends of the copper wire are held at different temperatures. Which t hey inevitably are because the meter mechanism or circuit is typically at a different temperature than the ends of its probe wires.) The measurement can be made with an ordinary DVM, but the set-up is very critical, and you won't get an actual reading of the target wire's Seebeck Voltage. The voltage reading you get from the DVM will only allow you to calculate the Seebeck voltage produced by the target wire.

Back to the thermocouple: In Ancient Times (1800's) the early EE geniuses figured out a way to coax the Seebeck Voltage out of the wire so it could be measured with early electromechanical meters (such as a galvanometer). They did this be using two wires composed of two different metals,  having two different Seebeck Coefficients (essentially volts/degree F), and thereby producing two different Seebeck voltages. It's the difference  between the Seebeck Coefficients of the thermomcouple's two wires that "produces" the "output voltage" you think you are  measuring from the thermocouple.

The junction of the thermocouple does NOT produce the  voltage. It's not a "little battery", nor is it a "chemical reaction" caused by the junction of the two dissimilar metals, nor is it a semiconductor-like effect as is found in diodes and transistors. All of these  common analogies have caused generations of EE's to be  mislead as to the actual operating principle of thermocouples.

Further, there are several other thermal-electric effects that occur simultaneously in the thermocouple mechanism that muddy the visibility of the Seebeck Effect. These are the Thompson Effect, the Peltier Effect and Joule heating. It's a miracle  that the Ancient Ones were able to figure  this all out with their primitive measuring instruments, but they did even if it took them several decades to do it.

Get yourself a good book on thermocouples and study it carefully to learn the real story of thermocouples.

Comment: This the best explanation of thermocouples I have found on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Normally (in the current era) thermocouples used for measurement purposes are used as a voltage source and are measured by a high-impedance measuring circuit. The voltage output with respect to **temperature difference** is always nonlinear (and dependent on the cold junction temperature), some thermocouples in some temperature ranges more than others. Because of the high impedance, the voltage does not depend much on the resistance of the thermocouple or extension wire (or any connectors).

If you heavily load the thermocouple heavily or short it out, of course  you'll get a current, and a relatively high current is possible since the source impedance of the thermocouple is quite low. This is used in some gas safety valves where a thermopile  (series connected thermocouples) is used to directly energize a gas valve, keeping it open as long as a flame is present. Very simple with little to go wrong. If you've used a gas appliance where you hold the valve open for some time until the flame remains lit, that's probably what's going on. The short-circuit current will depend on the resistance of the thermocouple wires, so heavy wires will yield more short-circuit current, however they'll obviously cause more heat flow between the regions at two different temperatures, so thermodynamics rears its head. I think there's also a slight heat flow effect due directly to the current flowing, much like a Peltier device (which is like a thermopile optimized for pumping heat).

Perhaps 50 or more years ago, it was common to have a moving coil meter movement connected directly to a thermocouple, perhaps with a bimetal spring to provide cold-junction compensation for lower temperature ranges and additionally perhaps some compensation for the copper winding temperature coefficient of resistance. That could even be used as a temperature controller by detecting the needle position using a vacuum tube amplifier (typically an oscillator and non-contact capacitance pickup) driving a mechanical relay. Such meters were factory calibrated for a specific resistance of thermocouple, such as 10\$\Omega\$, which would be printed on the scale, and you would have to order a thermocouple made with that resistance. The resistance of the wires varies with the length of the wires (usually fixed, obviously) but also the temperature of the wires along their length, so it introduces inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In a thermocouple current is created due to the thermal motion of free electrons.
The number of free electrons/volume for each material creating the thermocouple is also very important 
Take the thermocouple junctions(change of material) and use the Drude model for each junction and you will understand.